# Trouble installing Windows 10 over Elementary OS

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, elementaryos

I currently have Elementary OS (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) installed on my Lenovo Ideapad 100s, any I am having trouble trying to install windows 10.

I have tried using the bootable USB on another laptop and it worked fine.

These are my boot options:

[image: Boot Menu]

However when I select the USB option, it takes me straight to the GNU GRUB screen:

[image: GNU GRUB]

Do I have to somehow remove GRUB before installing windows? I have been at this for hours and can't find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

A simple fix may be completely formatting the laptop's storage drive using DBAN (http://www.dban.org/).  Then you could try installing Windows 10 on the clean drive.

**This would remove Linux along with anything else on the storage drive, so make sure you have any drivers/personal data need for the new Windows 10 install backed-up!**

Hope this helps!  Please remember to mark as solved and upvote if it did.